# Change style of parent element on clicking child element in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React,  I want to know how can I change the style of div with id "parent" while clicking of div with id "child".

```
<div id="parent"></div>

#parent{display:block;}

var Products=React:createClass({
    showHide: function(){
        // change style of parent id's "display:block" to "display:none"
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div id="child" onclick={this.showHide}>ABCD</div>
        );
});
ReactDOM.render(<Products />,document.getElementById('parent'));
```

Answer (score 5):

React handles this in a one-way data flow sort of way. Parent components communicate to child components through props, and child components communicate back to the parent through callback props. You need to pass a callback prop to the child component from the parent that will then update the parent's state, which then updates the style through either toggling the `style` prop (inline style) or toggling a CSS class using the `className` prop.

Here is an example where the child component updates the parent's foreground color using the `style` prop. `onTrigger` is just an example name since you didn't specify the context of why the child is updating the parent, but it can be named anything. The ChildComponent can use `onTrigger` to pass any data back to the parent, then the parent can handle it as needed, seen here in the `handleTrigger` function.

```
const ChildComponent = ({ onTrigger }) => (
  <div id="child" onClick={() => onTrigger("red")}>ABCD</div>
);

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set the initial state value
    this.state = { color: "green" };

    // One of a few ways to bind the function
    this.handleTrigger = this.handleTrigger.bind(this);
  }

  handleTrigger(color) {
    this.setState({ color: color });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="parent" style={{ color: this.state.color }}>
        <ChildComponent onTrigger={this.handleTrigger} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```