# React change mouse cursor/css on canvas

Tags: reactjs

I have a canvas (three.js) where I want to change the mouse cursor in my js-code. How can I achieve that in react? I can't use the standard react wa because I have to calculate the mouse over in my 3d scene which is shown in the canvas.

Comment: Are you rendering the cursor in the canvas yourself or can you use CSS?  In other words, does this fit your need: `canvas {cursor: url(hand.cur), pointer;}` from [MDN cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) or are you doing a `ctx.fillRect()` or whatever to have a canvas in the scene?

Comment: I want to change the css on the fly in my js code but the canvas is a parent component.

Comment: I have the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146696/change-style-of-parent-element-on-clicking-child-element-in-react